# Can I just substitute "hive" with "meld_beeline" while executing hql files in CLI

Tags: bash, unix, hive, bigdata, hiveql

Example:

**Instead of**
hive --hiveconf table=employee --hiveconf year=2019 -f sample.hql

**Can I use**
meld_beeline --hiveconf table=employee --hiveconf year=2019-f sample.hql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you're using bash, you can use variable substitution:

```
cmd=hive
$cmd --hiveconf table=employee --hiveconf year=2019 -f sample.hql
${cmd/hive/meld_beeline} --hiveconf table=employee --hiveconf year=2019 -f sample.hql
```

Comment: Thankyou. So, I can just replace hive with meld_beeline without changing any other options? And query will run in meld_beeline instead of hive?